# Run Invoke-Command on an array of computers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get result of `Test-Path` (or ultimately be able to run any command) on a list of computers that was returned from another query but I get wrong info for my return

This is my code

```
$AD_list = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
$py_path = "C:\Python39"
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList ($AD_list) -ScriptBlock {
  foreach ($machine in $AD_list) {
    Test-Path $py_path
  } 
}
```

Have tried passing `$AD_list` as `$args[0]` or declare it as a positional parameter `param([System.Collections.ArrayList]$AD_list)` but didn't work

I appreciate any clues or feedback.

Comment: What's "wrong info"? How exactly is it wrong compared to your expectations?

Comment: To the folk who added the tag for Active-Directory, this has nothing to do with AD lmao

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Command already accepts an array of hosts natively:

```
$hosts = ("hostA", "hostB", "hostC")

$results = Invoke-Command $hosts {Test-Path $using:py_path}
```

Note that you need `$using:X` in order to reference "outside" variables from within the script block.

The entire script block is already run on each machine, so if a `foreach` were needed, it would need to be located *outside* of the script block, not inside. For example:

```
foreach ($host in $hosts) { icm $host {Test-Path...} }
```

Similarly, `%` or `ForEach-Object` could be used here:

```
$hosts | % { icm $_ {Test-Path...} }
```

Comment: Thank you for you kind answer, I ended up using Invoke-Command inside the foreach

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Invoke-Command inside foreach and it worked for me

```
$AD_list = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name

foreach ($machine in $AD_list) {

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock { 

Test-Path "C:\Python39" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}

Write-Host "Results for $machine"

Write-Host $result

}
```